# Server with 3ware 8006-2LP won't stop beeping

Tags: hardware-raid, 3ware

A server I support startet beeping. One of the RAID-1 disks had an error.
I replaced the disk and rebuilt the array, but the server won't stop beeping
and one of the drive enclosures is blinking.
I tried to reboot and swaped the drive enclosures.

The RAID is working fine and I don't see any errors in the 3dm2 web interface
or somewhere else.

Does anyone know how to stop that beeping and blinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It wasn't a problem with the RAID controller.
The hard drive enclosure has an integrated fan and if the fan fails, it signals with beeping.

After changing the enclosure everything was fine.